# iOS 7.1 - How to call a selector without knowing name at compile time?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When my code gets to a certain point in execution, it needs to call a selector. Problem is, which selector to call, along with the object passed to it in performSelector, changes each time. The candidate selectors are all functions written ahead of time, but how can I convert from a variable (e.g.: NSString* or enum telling program which selector to call) to the name of the selector, without using a gigantic switch statement?

Comment: `[theObject performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(someNSString) withObject:someArgument];`

Comment: (or, if you need even more flexibility, use `NSInvocation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(aSelectorName);
if ([self respondsToSelector: selector])
{
    [self performSelector: selector];
}
```